# Plotting Photon Number Distribution of squeezed states in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, distributions, physics, histograms

I want to plot photon number distribution (PND) of even and odd photons in a single-mode squeezed vacuum state in Mathematica but I don't know how to plot.

The formula of PND is

$P_{2 n}=\frac{(\tanh r)^{2 n}}{\cosh r}\frac{(2 n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2 n}},P_{2n+1}=0$

where *r* is the squeezing parameter which is equal to 1. I want to plot like

[image]

If anyone knows please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is $r$ here?

Comment: In this case,  =1. @MassDefect

Comment: Use `DiscretePlot`.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks a lot.

Comment: @LCarvalho thank you very much for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 01:**

I misunderstood the indexing, so my original answer at the bottom is wrong.

```
data = Table[
  {2 n, N[Tanh[1]^(2 n)/Cosh[1] (2 n)!/((n!)^2 2^(2 n))]},
  {n, 0, 10}
];
ListPlot[
  data,
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(n\)]\)"},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]],
  PlotMarkers -> "",
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 20.5}, {0, 1}},
  Epilog -> {
    Rectangle[{#[[1]] - 0.5, 0}, {#[[1]] + 0.5, #[[2]]}] & /@ data
  }
]
```

[image]

**INCORRECT:**

Does something like this work for you? You can of course customize it using the options in the documentation for `DiscretePlot` to change the colours or add labels, etc.

```
DiscretePlot[
  If[EvenQ[n], Tanh[1]^(2 n)/Cosh[1] (2 n)!/((n!)^2 2^(2 n)), 0],
  {n, 0, 20},
  ExtentSize -> Full,
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 20.5}, {0, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Black
]
```

[image: Discrete plot of OP's equation.]

Comment: From OP picture for `n=2` is`p[n]=0.187944` ?
Something's not right here.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I did see that, but I wasn't sure if the value $r = 1$ is the same as what the poster's picture used or not. Looking at it again, I think I misunderstood the indexing. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll update it.

Comment: @MassDefect, thank you very much. This works

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thanks a lot.